# How to check if an apk launch successfully?

Tags: android, apk

While installing an apk in different devices, how would i come to know that my apk installed successfully in one device and failed to install in other device. Is there any command for that.

Comment: Your question confuses me.

To see if it failed and to get any output from the failure, check your logcat.

To see if it was successful, check your logcat.

Comment: Exactly, i mean, i want to launch an apk (using 'adb shell am start') on many devics, how can i know which device launch failed?

Comment: How are you viewing your logs? Best of my knowledge, Logcat will only show the output from one device at a time, with you having to switch to other devices in logcat to see their output.

thus in order to know this, you will have to switch to the next device you are going to launch on in your devices tab in logcat and then launch the app